# Property 'onRemove' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want create remove button for drag and drop items, when i save this code, compiling give error

**Property 'onRemove' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<{ value: string; } & SortableElementProps> & Readonly<...>'**.

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { arrayMove, SortableContainer, SortableElement } from 'react-sortable-hoc';

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}: {value: string}, onRemove)  =>
  <div className="dragItems" style={{background: 'gray'}}>{value}
    <button className="Button" onClick={() => onRemove(any)}>Remove {any}</button>
  </div>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({dragItems}: {dragItems: string[]}, onRemove) => {
  return (
    <div className="dragAndDrop">
      {dragItems.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={'item-${index}'} index={index} value={value} onRemove={onRemove} />
      ))}
    </div>  
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends React.Component<{}, {items: string[]}> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
    }
  }
  public render() {
    return  <SortableList 
          dragItems={this.state.dragItems} 
          onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
          lockAxis="xy"
          axis="xy"
          onRemove={(index: any) => this.remove(index)}
            />;
  }
  private onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}: {oldIndex: number, newIndex: number}) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };

  remove(index: any) {
    const items = this.state.items;
    items.splice(any, 1);

    this.setState({items : items})
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: and the implementation of sortablecontainer?

Comment: @jsdeveloper Yes, this list of items.  drag and drop work it's fine, but how i can correctly add remove button ?

Comment: In below i answer to my question and attach link for solution, this task is not relevant. Please delete this task

Answer (score 0):

Please close this task, problem is solved in another task, i attach link below.

[Delete an element by key from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950029/delete-an-element-by-key-from-array/56950549?noredirect=1#comment100443394_56950549)