# Delete an element by key from Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I used library [react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) for drag and drop element, but the library documentation does not have any actions for delete items. I want to delete, drag and drop item when click on close button. Which method is right for removing elements by key from object?

**React**

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value }: { value: string }, onRemove: any) =>
    <div className="dragItems" style={{ background: 'gray' }}>
        <img src={value} alt="" />
        <button className="dragCloseBtn" onClick={() => onRemove(any)} />
    </div>

);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }: { items: string[] }) => {
    return (
        <div className="dragAndDrop">
            {items.map((value, index) => (
                <SortableItem key={'item-${index}'} index={index} value={value} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
});

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [
            { 
                "id": 0, 
                "link": "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
            },
            { 
                "id": 1, 
                "link": "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
            }
        ],
    };
}

public onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }: { oldIndex: number, newIndex: number }) => {
    this.setState({
        items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
};

public onRemove(e: { target: { value: any; }; }) {
    const array = [...this.state.items]; 
    const index = array.indexOf(e.target.value)
    if (index !== -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({items: array});
    }
}

<SortableList items={this.state.items}
              onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
              lockAxis="xy"
              axis="xy" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Hi there, I figured out what went wrong and made a successful remove event on your application.

Everything is illustrated with comments at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-dhawan-i3uj1).

=========

I modified this one, it should do the required using Array's `filter` method.

```
public onRemove(e: { target: { value: any; }; }) {
    let array = [...this.state.items];
    const intId = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    array = array.filter(item => item.id !== intId);
    this.setState({items: array});
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, it seems that JSlent is asking for the second parameter for the `parseInt` method up there, It's been updated, can you please check it again? @Yavar

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RLaHCis0mZ5Sq4HZZRBIE9dO-mxgX-x4

Displayed this error

Comment: The component can't read `onRemove` function, I can't figure out the construction of your component file, I've got no experience with TS.

Did the function work before any of the edits suggested by me?

Comment: what about using `() => this.onRemove(any)` instead of `() => onRemove(any)`

Comment: Functionality drag and drop its work very well, but i can't remove items ( i try many functions, but all is not correct(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196194/discussion-between-yavar-and-sultan-h).

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please follow the comments out there in the link provided.

Comment: Sultan, thanks for solution and spent time for my task.

Answer (score 1):

So there were few problems in your code! You seemed to be confuse how react works with passing down props. You have to pass down the method required for remove. And you should bind it inside the class that you will be calling it.

> - onRemove should be bound to current context
> - onRemove should be passed down across the component tree
> - Check my //[NOTE]====> comments for additional explanation
> - Working code sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-morse-mhckt)

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  arrayMove,
  SortableContainer,
  SortableElement
} from "react-sortable-hoc";


//[NOTE]====>value contains the relevent object containing the callback. Onclick call it with the relevant id
const SortableItem = SortableElement(
  ({ value }: { value: any }, onRemove: any) => (
    <div className="dragItems" style={{ background: "gray", margin: "20px" }}>
      <img src={value.link} alt="" />
      <button className="dragCloseBtn" onClick={() => value.onRemove(value.id)}>
        {" "}
        X{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }: { items: string[] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="dragAndDrop">
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends React.Component<{}, { items: string[] }> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    //[NOTE]====>Send the callback on each element bound to the current context
    //This is like telling the function from where exactly the function will be called
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          id: 0,
          link: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
          onRemove: this.onRemove.bind(this)
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          link: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
          onRemove: this.onRemove.bind(this)
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  public render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
  public onSortEnd = ({
    oldIndex,
    newIndex
  }: {
    oldIndex: number;
    newIndex: number;
  }) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex)
    });
  };

  //[NOTE]====>Use the id to filter out and set the new set of items
  public onRemove(id) {
    console.log(id);
    let array = [...this.state.items];
    const intId = parseInt(id, 10);
    array = array.filter((item: any) => item.id !== intId);
    this.setState({ items: array });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SortableComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting help !! Great Job !